# django rest framework how to check if phone already exist?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to check if phone number is already existing or not.

My serializer

```
class teacherInfoCustomSer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'phone']
```

apiView

```
def teacherInfoCustom(request, pk):
    custom = CustomUser.object.get(id=pk)
    serializer = teacherInfoCustomSer(instance = custom, data = request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

and my JS

```
let data1 = JSON.stringify({
            "first_name": tch_name.value,
            "last_name": tch_lastname.value,
            "phone": tch_phone.value
        })
        const teacherInfoCustom = ('/p/teacherInfoCustom/' + "{{ request.user.id }}")
        fetch(teacherInfoCustom, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
            },
            body: data1,
        }).then((response) => {            
            console.log(response)
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err.response.message)
        })
```

In model's phone field

```
phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

and if a phone number already exist it won't give me status 400 but gives status 200 and it didn't save(i think because I set `unique=True` in my model). And if I enter phone number that didn't exist it will save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, regardless whether the `serializer` is valid or not, you return a response with the data and with status code `200`, since that is the default, you thus should return a different `Response` if the serializer failed:

```
def teacherInfoCustom(request, pk):
    custom = CustomUser.object.get(id=pk)
    serializer = teacherInfoCustomSer(instance=custom, data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        # ↓ only return if the serializer is valid
        return Response(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you're always returning `serializer.data` and never `serializer.errors`. A simple solution would be to use a [generic view](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#generic-views) for this.

For example:

```py
from rest_framework import generics
from .serializers import teacherInfoCustomSer

class CustomUserAPIView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = teacherInfoCustomSer
```